# Plot two smooth curves from a set of data with interlaced points

Tags: plotting, data, smoothing

I have a set of [data](https://www49.zippyshare.com/v/9OwmAldc/file.html) which was obtained from numerical calculation. The plot of the original data is as follows (the data is 26Kb only).

```
data = ToExpression /@ Import["~\\testdata.csv"];
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The data consist of interlaced points as can be seen in the enlarged view

```
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{1.88, 2.2}, {0.39, 0.42}}]
```

[image]

I hope to plot smooth curves to approximate these points and have tried `FindCurvePath`

```
curvetest = FindCurvePath[data];
Curvetest = ListLinePlot[{data[[curvetest[[1]]]], data[[curvetest[[2]]]]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It gives two smooth curves, but near the left and right interactions, some parts are lost in comparison with the original plot. I guess this could result from the points jumping up and down near the intersections and `FindCurvePath` cannot distinguish the rapid jump there.

**I have an idea to deal with this: (1) separate the data for the upper and lower curves, and (2) use `FindCurvePath` or some other method (e.g. `Fit`) to plot two smooth and complete curves.** But I have trouble in the first step. Can anyone help with this? Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you have a data set, let's say `data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};` then you can use `data[[;; 5]]` to pick the first five ones for example. Similarly, `data[[5 ;;]]` gives the last five entries of the original list. So, maybe you can use that to separate data and do your fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can divide `data` into two list as follows

```
up = Select[data, #[[2]] >= data[[2, 2]] &];
dw = Select[data, #[[2]] <= data[[1, 2]] &];
```

Now we can plot

```
{ListPlot[{up, dw}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
ListLinePlot[{up, dw}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> {{1.88, 2.2}, {0.39, 0.42}}, PlotStyle -> Blue]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. Second method based on hypothesis that there is a line dividing region on two parts and separating  curves as follows

```
data = ToExpression /@ 
  Import["C:\\Users\\troun\\Downloads\\testdata.csv"]; n = 
 Length[data]; l = 
 Interpolation[{data[[1]], (data[[n]] + data[[n - 1]])/2}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[l[x], {x, data[[1, 1]], First[(data[[n]] + data[[n - 1]])/2]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

```
up = Select[data, #[[2]] >= l[#[[1]]] &];

dw = Select[data, #[[2]] <= l[#[[1]]] &];

{ListPlot[{up, dw}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}],ListLinePlot[{up, dw}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> {{1.88, 2.2}, {0.39, 0.42}}, PlotStyle -> Blue]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Sorry, your method is not reliable because some points are lost, for example, the 2nd and 3rd point `{1.9, 0.4114}` and `{1.905, 0.41145}` should have been included in `up`.

Comment: @jsxs  See update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your data contains 2 y values for every x value. However, there is a bug, the exception is the 69'th point that does not have a pair. therefore delete point 69:

```
data = d0 = ToExpression /@ Import["d:/Downloads/testdata.csv"];
data = Delete[data, 69];
```

Now we separate the 2 curves using "Partition" and "Transpose":

```
data = Transpose[Partition[data, 2]];
```

Now we can interpolate and plot the resulting functions:

```
f1 = Interpolation[data[[1]]]
f2 = Interpolation[data[[2]]]

Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, Min[d0[[All, 1]]], Max[d0[[All, 1]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your method works exactly for the particular case. However, for my real problem, the data do include a number of bugs, that is, for some `x` it does not have a pair. Is there a more robust method that can tolerate the exceptions without the deleting process like Alex's method?

Comment: @jsxs it seems that would be a good question to make a new post about! That is, how to fix your data’s exceptions issues with a general method. After waiting a bit longer, I would recommend you accept your preferred answer for this question, and continue your path with the second question. I recommend waiting because someone may come along give an answer that includes this additional level of complexity you mention in the comments.